# Shape unknown member: invalid request. To select a shape, its view must be active

Tags: vba, selection, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint macro that takes pictures and adds them to an open slideshow. When I try to run the macro after clicking below the list of slides on the left of the screen (which causes a solid blinking horizonal bar underneath the last slide), I get the error:

```
Runtime error '-2147188160 (80042240)': 
Shape unknown member: invalid request. To select a shape, its view must be active
```

I figured this was because I didn't have a valid object selected so I added a debug statement to determine what the selection was:

```
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 0 Then
   MsgBox "0"
End If
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 1 Then
   MsgBox "1"
End If
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 2 Then
   MsgBox "2"
End If
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 3 Then
   MsgBox "3"
End If
```

The first image to get added causes a `1` to be displayed and the picture is added correctly but then error displays and macro stops. Annoyingly, when I try to run this in debug mode, it works every time. I can only assume I'm somehow manually fixing the problem on accident when I debug it.

The statement that's causing the problem:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(//file information//).Select 

//the line after
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Comment: could you provide more of your code? why do you need to select the shape after you add it- is it necessary??

Comment: @KazJaw Added more. Most of my code is "fluff". I'm honestly not sure if I need to select it. I didn't originally write it and I know very little about VBA. I'm definitely willing to rewrite it a different way if that will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's going on here.  If you/the user has clicked on the slide thumbnail in the thumbnails pane, the the active selection might be the Slide rather than the added picture.

You can get round this by doing something like this:

```
Dim oSh as Shape

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(//file information//)
oSh.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Just one of many reasons to use object references (oSh in this case) rather than working with a selection.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add your pictures when slide show is running you could do it this way, too:

```
Dim fileName, filename1, filename2
fileName = "c:\PROJEKT\....\Hydrangeas.jpg" 'your path +file name here
fileName1 = ... 'add other file path
fileName2 = ... 'add other file path

With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
    .AddPicture fileName, True, True, 10, 10, 100, 100
    .AddPicture fileName1, True, True, 30, 30, 100, 100
    .AddPicture fileName2, True, True, 50, 50, 100, 100
    '...etc.
End With
```

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide oSlide.SlideIndex
```

To activate the view before you select the shape on the slide.

More information can be found [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-office-powerpoint/486504-shape-unknown-member-invalidid-request-select-shape-its-view-must-active.html)